# Select Multiple column Group by one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone help me with this query ?

```
    SELECT CLIENT.ID_CLIENT ,
           EVALUATION_CLIENT.ID_EVAL ,
           MAX(EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date) AS DATE

FROM    EVALUATION_CLIENT

INNER JOIN CLIENT
    ON CLIENT.ID_CLIENT = EVALUATION_CLIENT.FK_IDClient

WHERE   EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date
            BETWEEN @START_DATE_LOCAL
            AND @END_DATE_LOCAL

GROUP BY    CLIENT.IDCLIENT,
            EVALUATION_CLIENT.ID_EVAL
```

Which it return...

```
ID_CLIENT | ID_EVAL    | DATE_EVAL
1423      |11160       | 2008-02-12 00:00:00.000
1423      |11161       | 2008-02-18 00:00:00.000
18        |11162       | 2008-02-15 00:00:00.000
666       |11163       | 2008-02-19 00:00:00.000
```

But I want something like (No duplicate Client)

```
ID_CLIENT | ID_EVAL    | DATE_EVAL
1423      |11161       | 2008-02-18 00:00:00.000
18        |11162       | 2008-02-15 00:00:00.000
666       |11163       | 2008-02-19 00:00:00.000
```

I use MSSQL 2008

Thank a lot !

**Update:** I need the Id_Eval for the most recent date by Id_client

Comment: Do you just want the highest ID_EVAL for each client?  Or do you want the one with the latest date?  Are those by definition the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to most recent entry for each client, you could use:

```
;WITH ClientEvals AS
(
    SELECT 
       c.ID_CLIENT ,
       e.ID_EVAL ,
       e.Date AS ClientDATE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID_CLIENT ORDER BY e.Date DESC) AS 'RowNo'
    FROM    
        dbo.EVALUATION_CLIENT e
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.CLIENT c ON c.ID_CLIENT = e.FK_IDClient
    WHERE   
        e.Date BETWEEN @START_DATE_LOCAL AND @END_DATE_LOCAL
)
SELECT       
   ID_CLIENT ,
   ID_EVAL ,
   ClientDATE
FROM
   ClientEvals
WHERE
   RowNo = 1
```

The inner select inside the CTE (Common Table Expression) selects the evals for each client, and partitions the data by `ID_Client` - each client gets row numbers from 1 on up, with 1 being the most recent entry.

The outer `SELECT` is based on that CTE and selects only those rows with `RowNo = 1` -> the newest ones for each client.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, if you only want the highest `ID_EVAL` for a `ID_CLIENT`:

```
SELECT CLIENT.ID_CLIENT ,
           MAX(EVALUATION_CLIENT.ID_EVAL),
           MAX(EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date) AS DATE

FROM    EVALUATION_CLIENT

INNER JOIN CLIENT
    ON CLIENT.ID_CLIENT = EVALUATION_CLIENT.FK_IDClient

WHERE   EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date
            BETWEEN @START_DATE_LOCAL
            AND @END_DATE_LOCAL

GROUP BY    CLIENT.IDCLIENT
```

Comment: Note that this could return the `ID_EVAL` from one row and the `Date` from another.  That may be fine, as the poster was unclear about the requirements -- but it seems more likely that they want to have both elements from the same row.  If it's guaranteed that a higher `ID_EVAL` will also have a later `Date`, then this would be fine in any case.

Comment: @Dave - true enough. Need more info from the OP to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will allow for the case `MAX(ID_EVAL)` isn't on the same row as the `MAX(EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date)`

If you don't have to worry about that condition use Oded's approach.

```
SELECT CLIENT.ID_CLIENT ,
       EVALUATION_CLIENT.ID_EVAL ,
       EVALUATION_CLIENT.Date
FROM   evaluation_client 
       INNER JOIN client 
         ON client.id_client = evaluation_client.fk_idclient 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT client.id_client, 
                          MAX(evaluation_client.DATE) AS DATE 
                   FROM   evaluation_client 
                          INNER JOIN client 
                            ON client.id_client = evaluation_client.fk_idclient 
                   WHERE  evaluation_client.DATE BETWEEN 
                          @START_DATE_LOCAL AND @END_DATE_LOCAL 
                   GROUP  BY client.id_client, 
                             evaluation_client.id_eval)maxdate 
         ON evaluation_client.DATE = maxdate.DATE 
            AND client.id_client = maxdate.id_client
```